# Inability to access the personal area in QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, osx, qgis-cloud

For several months I have been unable to access my area in QGIS Cloud to update the changes in the meantime made to the desktop version, also to the map in QGIS Cloud that I created at the time (which still continues to be usable to the July version) .
These are the latest versions that I use, having also tried without result with the previous ones:

```
QGIS 3.10
QGIS Cloud plugin 3.1.2
Python 3.8
OSX 10.15.1
```

Logging in, I receive the following error message:

```
2019-11-25T13:36:21     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
              encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
              self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
              self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
              self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
              self.send(msg)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
              self.connect()
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
              server_hostname=server_hostname)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
              session=session
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
              self.do_handshake()
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
              self._sslobj.do_handshake()
             ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

             During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

             Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/ninovillari/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 292, in check_login
              version_info=self._version_info())
              File "/Users/ninovillari/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 163, in check_login
              content = request.post(resource, data)
              File "/Users/ninovillari/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 569, in post
              return self.request(resource, method='POST', data=data)
              File "/Users/ninovillari/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 657, in request
              response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
              return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
              response = self._open(req, data)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
              '_open', req)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
              result = func(*args)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
              context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
              File "/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
              raise URLError(err)
             urllib.error.URLError:
```

Answer (score 2):

QGIS Cloud Support found this solution (and it works!) with Terminal.

```
sudo su # you will have to enter your password here
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/openssl
chown yourname /usr/local/etc/openssl
/Applications/QGIS3.10.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3 install_certificates_on_OSX.command
```

Control your version.

[https://github.com/qgiscloud/qgis-cloud-plugin/wiki/Resolving-certificate-problems-on-OSX]